# Saving multiple selected listbox from post

Tags: php, mysql, listbox

I can't find an answer to this, hopefully it's simple.

When a user selects multiple items in a `<select>`, how do I save all the items in the `<select>` to the database?

The `$_POST['listbox']` appears to be just one value, I need it to be an array like with `checkbox[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting `[]` after the name?

```
<select name="listbox[]" multiple>
```

Comment: No - I guess that is for collections of the same named element, what I'm after is saving all the option values in the <select>

Comment: @jimsmith - no, the above should get you an array named 'listbox' containing all of the selected options from that particular select. Try it and do a `print_r($_POST);` to check the result.

Comment: AHAH! it works. I did an echo and expected to see 'array' but instead it gave me one value from the array. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to check these websites:
[php_tutorial](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/array_checkbox.php) , 
[php checkboxes](http://www.computing.net/answers/webdevel/php-amp-checkboxes/1122.html)

Here a link for multiple values on select [multiple values](http://www.onlinetools.org/tricks/using_multiple_select.php)

Basically you have to define in the html side all attributes name for each checkbox with the same name, and from the server side iterate in that array using a foreach $key->$val

Comment: but i don't want checkbox values, there's too many options, it has to be a listbox

Comment: I added for multiple options on select... I overlooked the field ... but it is almost the same... just one name as an array and then iterate from the server side!!